# Foundation side-nav loses styling when appendingTo body from previous position in grid

Tags: jquery, css, append, zurb-foundation

The idea is to take this side-nav list of categories and have it scroll with the browser on scroll; no problem there.

```
$(function(){  
    var offset = 130;
    var duration= 500;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            //console.log('true');
            if($('#store-left:visible').length > 0 && $('#fixzor:visible').length == 0){
                $('#store-left').appendTo('body');
                $('#store-left').css('position','fixed').css('top','0px').css('left','0px');
                $('#fixzor').toggleClass('hide');
                $('ul#categories.side-nav').css('position','relative').css('left','0px').css('right','0px').css('background-size','100% 100%');
            }
        } else {
            //console.log('false');
            if($('#store-left:visible').length > 0 && $('#fixzor:visible').length == 1){
                $('#store-left').prependTo('#category-container').css('position','').css('top','').css('left','');
                $('#fixzor').toggleClass('hide');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that once the div is moved to a fixed position it loses some of its styling as if by magic.

The ul no longer stretches to fill the parent div. I've tried every hack I could think of and can't seem to understand why its suddenly losing its styling.

**Edit**

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row collapse" id="category-container">
        <div id="fixzor" class="large-2 medium-3 small-4 columns hide">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="large-2 medium-3 small-4 columns hide-for-small-only" id="store-left">
            <ul id="categories" class="side-nav">
                <li class="heading" style="text-align: center;"><h5 class="subheader">Categories</h5></li>
                <li class="active"><a class="active filter" href="javascript:void(0);" category-data="all">All Categories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="results" class="large-10 medium-9 small-12 columns">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.css` in jQuery can be coded like `$(selector).css({"position":"fixed", "top":"0px", "left":"0px"});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get the desired functionality using the above method, but i found a somewhat hackish solution to get the desired functionality, using a hidden div that unhides once a offset is reached from the top of the page. For anyone who might need to do something similar in the future with a responsive grid, here's the code, including the full page row and the product grid div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row collapse" id="category-container">
        <div class="large-2 medium-3 small-4 columns hide-for-small-only">
            <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">
                <div id="fixz0r" style="display: none; width:100%; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns "id="store-left">
                <ul id="categories" class="side-nav">
                    <li class="heading" style="text-align: center;"><h5 class="subheader">Categories</h5></li>
                    <li class="active"><a class="filter categories" href="javascript:void(0);" category-data="all" name-data="All Categories">All Categories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="results" class="large-10 medium-9 small-12 columns">

        </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var offset = 130;
var duration= 500;
var scrollt = null;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        //console.log('true');
        if($('#store-left:visible').length > 0){
            clearTimeout(scrollt);
            scrollt = setTimeout(function(){
                $('#fixz0r').show(0,function(){
                    var sum = parseInt($(document).scrollTop()- 130); 
                    $('#fixz0r').height(sum);
                });
            },100);
        }
    } else {
        //console.log('false');

        if($('#store-left:visible').length > 0){
            clearTimeout(scrollt);
            scrollt = setTimeout(function(){
                $('#fixz0r').hide().css('height','0px');
            },100);
        }
    }
});
```